# ReactPlayer want set playing but get warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-player

I try to play video use **ReactPlayer** and set the playing from state and get some error.

Here my code:

```
function App() {
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState("true");

  return(
  <ReactPlayer
        playing={playing}
        url={myvideo}
        muted={muted}
        onEnded={playNext}
      />
)}
```

This is the error:

> 0.chunk.js:31274 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `playing` of type `string` supplied to `ReactPlayer`, expected `boolean`.

Can someone explain to me why that is error, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message states, it expects `boolean` but initially in your `useState` you pass `"true"` which considered as `string`.

You need to use `boolean` type instead of `string` as the following:

```
const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(true);
```

See from the official documentation for [`playing` prop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player#props) as:

> `playing`: Set to `true` or `false` to pause or play the media